If a function is integrable and is of bounded variation, then must $\sum_{n\geq 1} f(n)$ converge?
Let $f:(0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function.
Assume that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx<\infty$ and that $\int_0^{\infty}|f'(x)|dx<\infty$.
Claim: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges.
I have tried a few things. My gut tells me to try applying the integral test but I need a monotone decreasing function to compare the series with.
My "bright" idea is to define a step function $g(x)=\sup_{x\geq n}f(x)$ on the interval $[n,n+1)$. Then $g(x)$ is monotone decreasing and bounds the function $\phi(x):=\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$ from above.
So $g(x)\geq \phi(x)\implies \int g dx \geq \int \phi dx=\sum_{n\geq 1} f(n)$ and if I can show $g(x)$ is finite then I am done.
It should be clear by the assumptions that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and that the function $f(x)$ is bounded. Does there exist a constant $M>0$ such that $\int Mf(x)dx \geq \int g(x)dx$? Because this would be fantastic.
Thank you for your help!

While this is a nice idea, it turns out not to work: $g(x)$ doesn't have to be integrable. For an example, suppose that $f(x)$ is essentially always $0$ except for thin peaks of height $2^{-m}$ near $x=2^m$ for every integer $m\ge1$. The total variation at the $m$th peak is $2\cdot 2^{-m}$ and so the total variation is bounded overall. However, $g(x)$ is essentially $2^{-m}$ everywhere on the interval $[2^{m-1},2^m]$, resulting in a contribution to its integral of about $\frac12$ from each of these infinitely many intervals.
A related idea should work: for every $n\ge1$, choose $x_n\in[n,n+1]$ such that $f(x_n) = \min_{x\in[n,n+1]} f(x)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge1} f(n) &= \sum_{n\ge1} \bigl( f(n) - f(x_n) \bigr) + \sum_{n\ge1} f(x_n) \\
&= \sum_{n\ge1} \int_n^{x_n} {-}f'(x)\,dx + \sum_{n\ge1} \int_n^{n+1} f(x_n)\,dx \\
&\le \sum_{n\ge1} \int_n^{n+1} |f'(x)|\,dx + \sum_{n\ge1} \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\,dx \\
&= \int_1^\infty |f'(x)|\,dx + \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx < \infty.
\end{align*}
